# Making Sense of a jQuery tutorial regarding the HTML/PHP side of the code

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm very confused as to what to do with [this tutorial's instructions](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/). I don't know how to take the Javascript that is defined and translate that into html code to execute the code.

Also, my ultimate goal here is to take images that are called in WordPress with this code:

```
echo apply_filters( 
    'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 
    sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', 
        $image_link, 
        $image_class, 
        $image_title, 
        $image ),
    $attachment_id, 
    $post->ID, 
    $image_class 
);
```

and this:

```
echo apply_filters( 
    'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 
    sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', 
        $image_link, 
        $image_title,
        $image ), 
    $post->ID 
);
```

And add a client-side watermark without affecting the original image. (Selling photographs)

Comment: You need to understand that PHP and JS work very differently - the former works before the page is sent to the user (server-side), while the latter works on the client-side, after the browser has received data from the server.

All you need is to know the class of the images that you want the script to apply the watermark to. You can check the class of the images that are generated by the code, or add your own class to them.

Comment: How do I execute the watermark.js script? The script info page says the following; "_Simply place the watermark.js right before the body closing tag and call wmark.init method. The init method gets an javascript object passed_" - Then after this all that I would need to do is ensure the classes match up?

Comment: I've added line breaks to the code to make sense of what was happening there. A one liner with a huge horizontal scrollbar is not good to read. Kudos for locating the relevant code +1

Comment: To add to @brasofilo's comments, I'd add that the edits to the question code would be an excellent way to format the code in your project. PHP (and Wordpress) authors don't wrap code nearly enough, in my view; it is a great way to improve code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those WooCommerce filter hooks will enable you to add the watermark class needed for the tutorial's Javascript to work.

You need to add in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'thumb_watermark_so_15992159', 15, 4 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'image_watermark_so_15992159', 15, 2 );

function thumb_watermark_so_15992159( $html, $attachment_id, $post_ID, $image_class )
{
    $watermarked = str_replace( 'class="', 'class="watermark ', $html );
    return $watermarked;
}

function image_watermark_so_15992159( $html, $post_ID )
{
    $watermarked = str_replace( 'class="', 'class="watermark ', $html );
    return $watermarked;
}
```

<sub>*Related Q&A: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)*</sub>

---